# Error in converting from string to int vectors

Tags: c++, string, vector, casting

There are two errors in the convert function saying that conversion to char doesn't exist. I am attempting to convert the string vectors into int vectors, but this char business keeps ruining everything :(. I tried casting `(char)` in front of the error but to no avail. Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Also, according to my lab rules, I cannot change anything inside my asciiToInt function. And the `system("pause")` is because I am using microsoft visual studio.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void input(vector<string> &largeString1, vector<string> &largeString2);
void convert(vector<string> largeString1, vector<string> largeString2, vector<int> &largeInt1, vector<int> &largeInt2);
int asciiToInt(char ch);
void add(vector<int> largeInt1, vector<int> largeInt2, vector<int> &finalInt);
void output(const vector<int> finalInt);

int main()
{
    vector<string> largeString1;
    vector<string> largeString2;
    vector<int> largeInt1(12, 0);
    vector<int> largeInt2(12, 0);
    vector<int> finalInt(13, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        input(largeString1, largeString2);
        convert(largeString1, largeString2, largeInt1, largeInt2);
        add(largeInt1, largeInt2, finalInt);
        output(finalInt);
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
void input(vector<string> &largeString1, vector<string> &largeString2)
{
    cout << "Input:" << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        cin >> largeString1[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        cin >> largeString2[j];
}
void convert(vector<string> largeString1, vector<string> largeString2, vector<int> &largeInt1, vector<int> &largeInt2)
{
    int size1 = size(largeString1);
    int size2 = size(largeString2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        int dynamicsize1 = size1 - i;
        largeInt1[11 - i] = asciiToInt(largeString1[dynamicsize1]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
        int dynamicsize2 = size2 - j;
        largeInt2[11 - j] = asciiToInt(largeString2[dynamicsize2]);
    }
}
int asciiToInt(char ch)
{
    return (ch - '0');
}
void add(vector<int> largeInt1, vector<int> largeInt2, vector<int> &finalInt)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        finalInt[12 - i] = largeInt1[11 - i] + largeInt2[11 - i];
    }
}
void output(const vector<int> finalInt)
{
    cout << endl << "Output:" << endl << endl << "The sum is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        cout << finalInt[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: When the compiler says it can't convert from one type to another it usually means there's something wrong with the logic of the code you've written. Telling the compiler "do it anyway" (that's what a cast says) doesn't fix the underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think your goal is to read two large numbers which represented by two strings and then calculate the sum of them.

First problem: Here you don't want a `vector<string>` for `largeStringX`, what you need is a `string` (or a `vector<char>`). Because `string` is a container that contains characters (i.e. `char`), while `vector<string>` is a container that contains some strings.

Second problem: To acquire the size (length) of the string, instead of `size(someString)`, you should use `someString.size()`.

Comment: when I try to solve the second problem, I get the problem:             "error: identifier "someString" is undefined. Am I missing a class file?

Comment: @e7kim Err... You should replace `someString` with the variable name of your string, such as `largeString1.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

The expressions `asciiToInt(largeString1[dynamicsize1])` and `asciiToInt(largeString2[dynamicsize2])` are invalid since `asciiToInt` expects a `char` and the type of both `largeString1[dynamicsize1]` and `largeString2[dynamicsize2]` is `std::string`. There is no way to convert a `std::string` to `char` by the compiler.

I am not able to suggest anything to fix the error since it's not clear to me what your program is supposed to do.